# Using Sql to Manipulate data a certain way into a new table

Tags: sql

Alright, so this is my second time ever asking a question on stackoverflow, and this one I believe is a little complex. If you need any extra information let me know and I will provide it, and thanks for all replies/answers!

Basically I want to take this existing table with columns as follows:

```
Dealer
Open24
Mopen
Mclosed
Topen
Tclosed
Wopen
Wclosed
THopen
THclosed
Fopen
Fclosed
SAopen
SAclosed
SUopen
SUclosed
```

I want to keep this table the same, but I want to make a new table using this data using sql to insert the data in this table into the new table. This new table would look as follows:

```
Day      |  Open  |  Closed  | Dealer
Monday      0:00     9:00
Tuesday     0:00     14:00
...
Sunday      0:00     12:00
```

Dealer would be the foreign key to the table above. I have looked into pivoting data, but all I have seen is how to convert rows to columns. If anyone has a solution to this it would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Removed the conflicting and irrelevant tags.  Please re-tag your question with the DBMS you're using (e.g. `SQL Server`, `MySQL`, `Oracle`, or something else).

Comment: Can you post some sample input as well?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One method uses `union all`:

```
select Dealer, 'Monday' as dow, Mopen as "open", Mclosed as "closed"
from t
union all
select Dealer, 'Tuesday' as dow, Tuopen as "open", Tuclosed as "closed"
from t
union all
. . .
```

Creating another table depends on the dialect of SQL.  Often `create table newTable as` works.

Answer (score 2):

If you use SQL Server you can use Table Value Constructor to unpivot the data.

```
SELECT  
    mt.Dealer,
    ca.*
FROM    
    myTable mt 
CROSS APPLY ( VALUES
    ('Monday', Mopen, Mclosed),
    ('Tuesday', Topen, Tclosed),
    ('Wednesday', Wopen, Wclosed),
    ('Thursday', THopen, THclosed),
    ('Friday', Fopen, Fclosed),
    ('Saturday', SAopen, SAclosed),
    ('Sunday', SUopen, SUclosed)) ca([Day],[Open],[Closed])
```

Comment: That's possible with other DBMS as well (using the standard `lateral join` instead of `cross apply`)

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name mysql have an equivalent?

Comment: Not, but Postgres, Oracle and other DBMS that support [modern SQL](http://modern-sql.com/)

Answer (score 0):

```
CREATE TABLE pivot_dealer 
AS
SELECT 'Monday' AS day, Mopen AS Open, Mclosed AS Closed, Dealer
  FROM Dealer
UNION ALL
SELECT 'Tuesday' AS day, Topen AS Open, Tclosed AS Closed, Dealer
  FROM Dealer
UNION ALL
SELECT 'Wednesday' AS day, Wopen AS Open, Wclosed AS Closed, Dealer
  FROM Dealer
UNION ALL
SELECT 'Thursday' AS day, Thopen AS Open, Thclosed AS Closed, Dealer
  FROM Dealer
UNION ALL
SELECT 'Friday' AS day, Fopen AS Open, Fclosed AS Closed, Dealer
  FROM Dealer
UNION ALL
SELECT 'Saturday' AS day, Sopen AS Open, Sclosed AS Closed, Dealer
  FROM Dealer
UNION ALL
SELECT 'Sunday' AS day, Suopen AS Open, Suclosed AS Closed, Dealer
  FROM Dealer
;
```